# How to maniuplate text in first column of CSV file with script

Tags: string, powershell, csv, text, quotes

Have a CSV file with multiple columns with information. Need to remove the opening and closing `"` in the `Employee Name` as well as the `,` as seen below.

```
Employee Name,Employee #,column3, column4 etc. <br>
"Lastname, Firstname",123,abc,xyz<br>
"Lastname, Firstname",123,abc,xyz<br>
```

Result:

```
Employee Name,Employee #,column3, column4 etc.<br>
Lastname Firstname,123,abc,xyz<br>
Lastname Firstname,123,abc,xyz<br>
```

Tried using the following Powershell script:

```
(gc C:\pathtocsv.csv) | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file C:\pathtocsv.csv -Fo -En ascii
```

This only removes the `" "` around `Lastname , Firstname` but the comma is still present when opening the csv file in a text editor. Need this format to send to data to another company. Everything I have tried removes every comma. Novice in powershell and other languages, I am sure this is an easy fix. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Powershell has a lot of built-in handling for CSV files, instead of trying to treat is as a text file you can use the following to remove just the comma you want:

```
Import-Csv .\a.csv | % {
    $_."Employee Name" = ($_."Employee Name" -replace ',','')
    $_ #return modified rows
} | Export-Csv .\b.csv -notype -delim ','
```

this will by default export everything with double quotes, so you may need to go back and run something like:

`(gc .\b.csv -raw) -replace '"','' | Out-File .\c.csv`

to also remove all the double quotes.

Comment: colsw, the solution you provided worked! I tried the first solution but put everything in a single column.

I cannot thank you enough for this. Now I need to put a powershell script on my manager's computer to take any csv file and output it so it can be sent out bi-weekly.
Thanks again!

Comment: @BryanW no problem - if it's all going into one column when opened in excel that's probably an issue with your system delimiter not being a comma (default semicolon a lot of the time) - you can change (or remove) the `-delim ','` part at the end of the code to match. if this answered your question feel free to accept the answer with the tick under the up/downvote buttons so other people can see it's closed.

Comment: very cool,never used `%`  and `$_ #return modified rows` .what do they mean

Comment: @TheGameiswar `%` is just an alias for `Foreach-Object`, the `$_` is the 'current pipeline object' inside the foreach, so I modify a property on it, then pass it back to the pipeline so it can be exported, the `#return modified rows` bit is just a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Warning: quotes are important if text contains special characters (i.e. comma, quote)

If you really want to strip lines, you can process your csv as regular text file:

```
#sample data
@'
"Lastname, Firstname",123,abc,xyz
"Lastname, Firstname",123,abc,xyz
'@ | out-file c:\temp\test.csv

Get-Content c:\temp\test.csv | % {
    $match = [Regex]::Match($_,'"([^,]*), ([^"]*)"(.*)')
    if ($match.Success) {
        $match.Groups[1].Value+' '+$match.Groups[2].Value+$match.Groups[3].Value
    } else {
        $_ #skip processing if line format do not match pattern
    }
}
```